# Which of these approaches to parallelise an async method is the most appropriate?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a single method that takes a filename of an image and processes the image (CPU intensive), then uploads it to blob storage (async IO). Here is a method summary:

```
public async Task<ImageJob> ProcessImage(String fileName) {

    Byte[] imageBytes = await ReadFileFromDisk( fileName ).ConfigureAwait(false); // IO-bound

    Byte[] processedImage = RunFancyAlgorithm( imageBytes ); // CPU-bound

    Uri blobUri = await this.azureBlobClient.UploadBlob( processedImage ).ConfigureAwait(false); // IO-bound

    return new ImageJob( blobUri );
}
```

The other part of my program receives a list of thousands of filenames to be processed.

What is the most appropriate way of calling my `ProcessImage` method in a way that makes maximum use of available IO and CPU power?

I've identified six different ways (so far) for calling my method - but I'm unsure which is the best:

```
String[] fileNames = GetFileNames(); // typically contains thousands of filenames

// Approach 1:
{
    List<Task> tasks = fileNames 
        .Select( fileName => ProcessImage( fileName ) )
        .ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}

// Approach 2:
{
    List<Task> tasks = fileNames 
        .Select( async fileName => await ProcessImage( fileName ) )
        .ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}

// Approach 3:
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach( String fileName in fileNames )
    {
        Task imageTask = ProcessImage( fileName );
        tasks.Add( imageTask );
    }

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}

// Approach 4 (Weirdly, this gives me this warning: CS4014 "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."
// ...even though I don't use an async lambda in the previous 3 examples, why is Parallel.ForEach so special?
{
    ParallelLoopResult parallelResult = Parallel.ForEach( fileNames, fileName => ProcessImage( fileName ) );
}

// Approach 5:
{
    ParallelLoopResult parallelResult = Parallel.ForEach( fileNames, async fileName => await ProcessImage( fileName ) );
}

// Approach 6:
{
    List<Task> tasks = fileNames
        .AsParallel()
        .Select( fileName => ProcessImage( fileName ) )
        .ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}

// Approach 7:
{
    List<Task> tasks = fileNames
        .AsParallel()
        .Select( async fileName => await ProcessImage( fileName ) )
        .ToList();

    await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
}
```

Comment: ever mix async/await and and `Parallel.ForEach` they are incompatible, it causes you to generate a `async void` function. You need to use [TPL instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: for your warning message (approach 4). Refer to here for an explanation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/ . In short, `async` keyword enables `await` keyword, it means if you want to use the `await` keyword, your method must be `async`, it does not mean that you don't need to use `await` if your method is not `async`.

Comment: @KhanhTO I know that - but for some reason the compiler warns me in Approach 4, but it does not warn me in Approach 1, even though the lambda is identical.

Comment: @Dal The lambda aren't identical because of type inference. In approach 1, the lambda returns a task. In approach 4, the lambda returns nothing (because `Parallel.ForEach` expects an `Action`, not a `Func<Task>`)

Comment: I would recommend TPL Dataflow.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have many items that need to be processed in exactly the same way. As @StephenCleary mentioned [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) is great for the type of problem. A great intro can be found [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/09/introduction-to-dataflow-part-1.html). The simplest way to start would be with just a couple of blocks with your main `TransformBlock` executing `ProcessImage` Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
public class ImageProcessor {

    private TransformBlock<string, ImageJob> imageProcessor;
    private ActionBlock<ImageJob> handleResults;

    public ImageProcessor() {
        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
            BoundedCapacity = 1000,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
        };
        imageProcessor = new TransformBlock<string, ImageJob>(fileName => ProcessImage(fileName), options);
        handleResults = new ActionBlock<ImageJob>(job => HandleResults(job), options);
        imageProcessor.LinkTo(handleResults, new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });           
    }

    public async Task RunData() {
        var fileNames = GetFileNames();
        foreach (var fileName in fileNames) {
            await imageProcessor.SendAsync(fileName);
        }
        //all data passed into pipeline
        imageProcessor.Complete();
        await imageProcessor.Completion;
    }

    private async Task<ImageJob> ProcessImage(string fileName) {
        //Each of these steps could also be separated into discrete blocks

        var imageBytes = await ReadFileFromDisk(fileName).ConfigureAwait(false); // IO-bound

        var processedImage = RunFancyAlgorithm(imageBytes); // CPU-bound

        var blobUri = await this.azureBlobClient.UploadBlob(processedImage).ConfigureAwait(false); // IO-bound

        return new ImageJob(blobUri);
    }

    private void HandleResults(ImageJob job) {
        //do something with results
    }
}
```